# sqldf corrupts utf-8 Values

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, sqldf

Running a query using sqldf outputs garbled characters when the query results include characters such as: `é`,`š`.

When I checked the encoding of those fields in the original df, they are specifically UTF-8, but after the query with sqldf, they become "unknown" (which is the normal values if the string can be encoded using ASCII).

I converted the column to character (using as.character) but I still encounter this problem. In the documentation of sqldf I did not find a way to determine the query output encoding.

Comment: This works fine for me: `mydf <- data.frame(column=c("1","xéy","yyšxx"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE); sqldf("SELECT * FROM mydf")`

Comment: I am using Windows 8.1 and  "R version 3.2.3 Patched (2016-01-12 r69945)" and zx8754's example works in Rgui for me too.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This works well for me too. I think it has to do with the fact that I import from CSV (working with RStudio). After view() of the df based on the CSV, the characters look fine. But when saving the query of sqldf to a new df, the characters are corrupted. So something has to tell sqldf to keep the utf-8 encoding, but I'm not sure how... (I do instruct R to do it explicitly when importing the CSV, using encoding=UTF-8, together with stringsasfactors=false).

Comment: ...I use Windows7; RStudio, 0.99.467.; R3.2.3.

Comment: Is there any solution to that problem?